# Are there any journals/studies on the benefits of full range of motion when doing an exercise?

Tags: exercise, strength, form, athletic-performance

I am quite curious if there are any papers in doing a full range of motion and the benefits towards them. Specifically, By training the full Range of motion, 1. Reduce muscular strength imbalances, More Muscle Development, Better Mobility, Reduced Injury Risk Healthier joints etc?

Comment: Hi Milan, welcome to Fitness.SE. Could you specify your question? This question is very broad which will most likely results in none specific and unclear answers asewll.

Comment: Yes, just done.

Comment: @Milan Do you mean how to perform full range of motion or what is the point on doing them

Comment: @Twyxz yes, i do mean the full range of motion

Comment: @Milan Why do you want evidence that it is better, How are you going to train otehrwise? You can simply feel the difference between training full reps and half reps

Comment: its not the benefit of myself, i would just like some sort of creditable source

Comment: There are lots of studies. Google has a wonderful [search sub engine](https://scholar.google.com) specifically for scholarly works, which has items such as this: https://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/Fulltext/2004/08000/An_Analysis_of_Full_Range_of_Motion_vs__Partial.22.aspx and this: https://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/Fulltext/2012/08000/Effect_of_Range_of_Motion_on_Muscle_Strength_and.17.aspx